# Need to get results grouped by fields and column value as name

Tags: mysql, query, pivot

I have table as below

| reported_date | url | stautus_code | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-20 | example.com | 200 | India |
| 2022-02-29 | example.com | 200 | US |
| 2022-01-20 | example.com | 200 | France |
| 2022-01-20 | sample.com | 200 | India |
| 2022-02-29 | sample.com | 200 | US |
| 2022-01-20 | sample.com | 200 | France |

Result should be of the below table structure

[image]

Basically we group by reported_date, country and count where status_code is 200.

Comment: The keyword to search for is "pivot".

Answer (score 0):

Do it in 2 steps.  First filter and get the counts:

```
SELECT url, country, LEFT(date,7) AS yyyymm, COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM ...
    WHERE status = "200"
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
    ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Then write the "pivot", using that as input:

```
SELECT URL, country,
       COALESCE(SUM(IF(yyyymm = '2022-12', ct, 0), 0) AS '2022/12',
       COALESCE(SUM(IF(yyyymm = '2023-01', ct, 0), 0) AS '2023/01',
       ...
    FROM ( the above query )
    GROUP BY 1,2
    ORDER BY 1,2
```

See this for a way to automate it:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Comment: considering that i have data for few years and i need to group  data for each month year, in that case i wont be able to put IF condition with date hardcoded and Alias hardcoded.
Is there way that it gets auto populated

Comment: @santosh - That's where my blog with its Stored Procedure becomes useful.

Comment: My Current Query is
select url, count(status_code), DATE_FORMAT(reported_date,'%Y-%m') as label, country from DownloadEntries where status_code=200 group by download_url, DATE_FORMAT(reported_date,'%Y-%m'), country;

Comment: Oops.  If fixed that.